# Where to find a cable that splits stereo into left and right sound?

Tags: stereo

I want to set up 2 Bluetooth speakers to create stereo sound via an audio cable that can separate audio (left and right) into each speaker.

I am having a hard time finding one that isn't intended for "listening to stereo music with a friend."

Any recommendations for a 3.5 mm audio cable that does this?

Comment: Do the speakers have 3.5 mm mono inputs?

Comment: I'm pretty sure they are stereo inputs, but I want to force mono since I will have two Bluetooth speakers on either end of my desk

Answer (score 1):

I assume the 3.5mm is for your device output. But what input options do you have for your speakers? What are the exact speakers you're dealing with? as *edwina oliver* said, it sounds like you're looking for a Y-cable. Here's an eighth-inch TRS to split quarter-inch TS:

https://www.sweetwater.com/store/detail/IPMB2Q5--pro-co-ipmb2q-5-5-foot

TRS stands for Tip-Ring-Sleeve, which respectively carry the left signal, right signal, and ground. Splitting this into two TS paths gives you your separated L/R signal. Again, since we don't know your speaker setup, it's difficult to solve your problem directly. You can also use Sweetwater's Cable Finder which should be somewhat self-explanatory in telling you what you need:

https://www.sweetwater.com/shop/cables/finder.php

If you need eighth-inch jacks all around, I don't believe I saw this in a Y-cable from Sweetwater, unfortunately. I'm sure they exist, so you can look elsewhere if you want. But I did see an eighth-inch TRS male to split eighth-inch TS female, with which you could use two more "aux" cords.

Hope this helps.

Comment: My speakers can only take 3.5 mm, but I suppose I could use an adapter

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you'll find a stock cable to do that simply because the Bluetooth speakers will have a stereo input and you want both tip and ring on one side to carry the left signal, and tip and ring on the other side to carry the right signal.  If you use an "insert cable" (which are mostly available for 6.3mm though), you end up with two mono plugs which effectively have the ring shorted to ground, meaning that the right input channel on either bluetooth speaker will be dead, resulting in only half the speaker doing actual work.

So your best bet is likely to wire/solder your own splitter that has one TRS plug for the input source and two TRS plugs for output, and then you wire T (tip) from the input plug to TR (both tip and ring) on the left output plug, R (ring) from the input plug to TR (both tip and ring) on the right output plug and, since you'll be using shielded wire for that, run the shield from the input plug to both output plugs' shield.

The laziest way to solder this is likely getting the cheapest earphones you can find (dollar shop?) and cutting off the earphones, replacing them with 3.5mm TRS plugs that have T and R wired to the center wire and S to the shield.

Answer (score -1):

Amazon

Best Buy

Many other stores

It is a Y type cable with stereo on one end and L & R on the other two ends.

Comment: Please read highly upvoted answers, and [answer] to see what we need in answer posts. That is your best route to gain upvotes and avoid downvotes.